# How to navigate in chrome's prompts using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm doing some automated tests on a web app using chrome experimental features (usb...etc) and selenium python. At some point I want to connect to a usb device through our web app but I'm unable to navigate to chrome's device selection prompt to select the device and agree to the connection.

[image: chrome usb prompt]

A few things, I already tried:

- switching to the alert (this is not an alert so I'm greeted with an error message saying there is no alert)

```
   def open_connection(self):
       # Click on the open button
       open_bt_xpath = "//button[contains(text(), 'Open')]"
       self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(open_bt_xpath).click()
       # Chrome user prompt is opening, switch to it
       alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert()
       alert.send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform()
       alert.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()
       alert.send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

=> `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:242: NoAlertPresentException`

- pressing buttons to select the device I want (again buttons (TAB,ENTER,ARROW_DOWN) seem to have no effect on the prompt)

```
    def open_connection(self):
        # Click on the open button
        open_bt_xpath = "//button[contains(text(), 'Open')]"
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(open_bt_xpath).click()
        # Chrome user prompt is opening, send keys to manually select the device
        action = ActionChains(self.driver)
        action.send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform()
        action.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()
        action.send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

- clicking at some specific offset where the device name is (again no effect on the prompt whatsoever)
- the prompt's code is not part of my web page so I can't see any of the prompt's code in chrome's dev tools nor can I find an element of the prompt directly by its tag or xpath

Do you guys know whether it's possible to navigate in such prompt ?

Comment: Can you give the code?

Answer (score 0):

Grab the xpath of the button by right clicking, hitting copy, followed by copy xpath from the drop down list, and then finally use:-

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path-to-chromedriver')
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
element.click()
```

Comment: This is a chrome user prompt and therefore not an element of my page so I can't just search for the element and click on it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find an answer after all:
Instead of trying to navigate in the prompt which was apparently impossible, I just had to modify chrome's policies when spawning Chrome so that my usb device gets automatically accepted by my web app:

```
    option = [{
        "devices": [{
            "vendor_id": MY-VENDOR-ID
        }],
        "urls": [
            "http://my-web-app.com"
        ]
    }]

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("enable-experimental-web-platform-features")
    options.add_experimental_option(
        'prefs', {
            'profile.managed_web_usb_allow_devices_for_urls': option
        }
    )
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

You can find a comprehensive list of policies here:
https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/chrome/test/data/policy/policy_test_cases.json